# Firebase from Node: no response from callback?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I'm trying to get Hello World working here -- just get my Node script to talk to Firebase. I made a script I think should read the "stories" collection, but I get no response from Firebase. I'm sure I'm missing something incredibly basic. Please help!

```
var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref("stories");

ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
}, function (errorObject) {
  console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
console.log('exiting');
```

...but what I get is:

```
p:0: Browser went online.
p:0: Listen called for /stories default
exiting
p:0: Making a connection attempt
p:0: Auth token refreshed
getToken() completed. Creating connection.
c:0:0: Connection created
c:0:0:0 Websocket connecting to wss://*****.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5
```

I kludged on a way to wait longer, and got this:

```
p:0: Browser went online.
p:0: Listen called for /stories default
exiting
p:0: Making a connection attempt
p:0: Auth token refreshed
getToken() completed. Creating connection.
c:0:0: Connection created
c:0:0:0 Websocket connecting to wss://*****.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5
c:0:0: Closing unhealthy connection after timeout.
c:0:0: Closing realtime connection.
c:0:0: Shutting down all connections
c:0:0:0 WebSocket is being closed
p:0: data client disconnected
p:0: Trying to reconnect in 0ms
0: onDisconnectEvents
p:0: Making a connection attempt
getToken() completed. Creating connection.
c:0:1: Connection created
c:0:1:0 Websocket connecting to wss://*****.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5
c:0:0:0 Websocket connection was disconnected.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Cloud Firestore and the Realtime Database are completely separate databases. Please only tag with the one that is relevant to your question. I fixed it for you now, but it's best if you do this yourself, so that we can focus on helping more people.

Comment: It seems your Node.js script exits before it gets the data from Firebase. Note that it is normal to see your `exiting` log before the `console.log(snapshot.val());`, as the latter is an asynchronous callback. Where are you running this code?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: I'm just doing "node foo.js" from the command line on my local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you talked about `collection`, so I think you're working on Cloud Firestore, not Realtime Database.
So the code should be:

```
const db = admin.firestore();
db.collection('stories').get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);
    });
```

Please have a look this image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlZMf.jpg)

Comment: Thanks! Doesn't that have to be db.collection('colName').doc('docName').get()?

Comment: you can use it to get detail of a document.
`db.collection('stories').get()`  -> it return a Promise of all documents of the `stories` document.
`db.collection('colName').doc('docName').get()`. -> it return a Promise of a single document (the docName). So, use this if you just want to get detail of a document and you know its docName

Answer (score 0):

Tru `once()` instead of `on()`.  `once()` just queries a single time and returns a promise.  `on()` establishes a listener that run until you remove it, and it doesn't return a promise.

```
ref.once('value')
.then(snapshot => {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
})
.catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
});
```